# Decide for which real numbers a, b, c the vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$
    v_1=\begin{bmatrix}
    a \\
    a^2 \\
    a^3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\
$$

$$
    v_2=\begin{bmatrix}
    b \\
    b^2 \\
    b^3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\
$$

$$
    v_3=\begin{bmatrix}
    c \\
    c^2 \\
    c^3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}\
$$

When I try to create a matrix and try to solve for $a$, $b$ and $c$ I just simply get that $a=b=c=0$, however this would not make the vectors linearly independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you attempted, you would first want to juxtapose column vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ to an order $3$ matrix
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
a^3 & b^3 & c^3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Then note that $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent if and only if $\det(A) \neq 0$. To find $\det(A)$, using the [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix):
\begin{align*}
\det(A) = abc\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
a & b & c \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2
\end{vmatrix} = abc(b - a)(c - a)(c - b).
\end{align*}

Therefore $\det(A) \neq 0$ if and only if $abc \neq 0$ and $a, b, c$ are all distinct.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped me!